# Invalid parameter number, PDO on duplicate update fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created following function in users class:

```
public function update_usermeta($user_id,$user_profile)
    {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO users_meta
                            (user_id,meta_key,meta_value)
                     VALUES (:user_id,:meta_key,:meta_value)
                         ON DUPLICATE KEY
                     UPDATE meta_value = :meta_value';

        foreach ($user_profile as $meta_key => $meta_value) {
            if ($meta_value == null OR $meta_value == "") {continue;}
            if ($meta_key == "identifier" OR $meta_key == "photoURL" OR $meta_key == "displayName" OR $meta_key == "email") {continue;}
            $params = array(
                ':meta_key'   => $meta_key,
                ':meta_value' => $meta_value,
                ':user_id'    => $user_id
            );
            $this->mysql_execute_query($sql,$params);
        }
}
```

Insert works fine, but I've problem with ON DUPLICATE part, it errors out with:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number
```

Obviously problem is that I've more parameters, than update requires. How do I resolve this situation?

Comment: Just use `UPDATE meta_value = VALUES(meta_value), user_id=VALUES(user_id)`, don't try to bind the same parameter multiple times, it's not needed.

Comment: @Wrikken ok, but that means that meta_value will not get updated with new value, correct?

Comment: quite the contrary, it _will_ update it with the _new_ value, which is [what that `VALUES()` function is for](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values)

Comment: I'll upgrade it to a more in-depth answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A @CertaiN mentions, with *real* prepares, non emulated ones, you can't bind the same variable multiple times by the same name. You could opt for binding it with another name, but this query does not need it. [The `VALUES()` function returns the value that would have been inserted](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values), which would make this query:

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users_meta
         (user_id,meta_key,meta_value)
       VALUES (:user_id,:meta_key,:meta_value)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY
       UPDATE meta_value = VALUES(meta_value)';
```

And can be used for more columns if needed, like so:

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users_meta
         (user_id,meta_key,meta_value)
       VALUES (:user_id,:meta_key,:meta_value)
       ON DUPLICATE KEY
       UPDATE 
         meta_value = VALUES(meta_value),
         meta_key = VALUES(meta_key)';
```

Answer (score 5):

It depends on **emulation** settings.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, $boolean);
```

If `$boolean === true`**(default value for PHP 5.2 or newer)**, duplicated place holders are valid.
If `$boolean === false`, they are invalid.

Here's my article about PDO Tips in Japanese.

#### [Qiita - PHPでデータベースに接続するときのまとめ](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/b00b72c5c95aac573b71)

I'll translate the part related to this issue...

## About Emulation

#### Is performance good enough?

ON   -> Yes
OFF -> So-So

#### Is `SET NAMES utf8` safe enough?

ON   -> So-So(Use DSN `charset` parameter)
OFF -> Yes(Use DSN `charset` parameter)

#### Can I get SQL `NULL` as PHP `NULL`?

ON   -> Yes
OFF -> Yes

#### Can I get SQL `int` as PHP `int`?

ON   -> No
OFF -> Yes

## Are duplicated place holders valid?

**ON   -> Yes**
**OFF -> No**(You should use `?` place holders.)

#### Do `PDO::PARAM_*` constants convert parameters into correct type?

ON   -> No **(Convert it manually, e.g. `(int)$value`, `intval($value)`)**
OFF -> Yes

#### Is `$stmt->bindParam()` safe on a side effect issue?

ON   -> No(All referenced variables are converted into string after execution...)
OFF -> Yes

Comment: Yes, I've set it to false.

Comment: Nice summary of the differences, +1.

Comment: Wow. Someone who have a clue. What a rare guest here.

Comment: Some items are questionable though

Comment: - SET NAMES utf8 is safe either way, even if you're using addslashes(). ` SET NAMES GBK` is a problem charset.

Comment: What are bindParam() side effect issues?

Comment: +1, though it doesn't answer my problem directly, this is awesome to know. thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you please explain how turning off emulation could lead to performance degradation? Kind of counterintuitive.

Comment: @salivan Emulated prepared statements are quickly built as normal query only on PHP itself, however, native prepared statements are required communicating with MySQL server. If MySQL server is remote, furthermore, it is done via very slow Internet traffic...